# How to send live audio stream from angular to python flask server using Socket.io?

Tags: angular, python-3.x, flask, socket.io

I got a python code from https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/streaming-recognize#speech-streaming-mic-recognize-python and i used it to to convert my speech to text with flask , but i am not able to send audio from Angular to flask on live streaming and get the output from server.Because i don't want to send audio in flac type, i directly want to send live stream from angular to flask server using google speech to text api.

Comment: Did you find any solutions to this? I am also trying something similar.